# Is it possible to SSH into a Virtual Machine instance using google-api-client rather than command line

Tags: gcloud, google-api-client

I want to automate the entire process from starting an instance to running a program on that instance.

So just as running a python program on a local computer requires only one command on command line, so too would I like to run my program on a remote VM instance with just one command.

It seems though that in order to SSH into a remote VM instance I have to use command line and I have to answer some yes/no questions or multiple choice questions. Admittedly you can use the sub process module but I have not yet figure out how to answer the yes/no questions.

Before I do more research however, I need to know if what I'm doing is even possible.  So I would like to build a python program using `google-api-client` which automates the entire process from starting the instance to connecting the instance to a drive, to running a program.

It seems though I cannot SSH into a remote VM instance with python but have to do this with command line.  Is this right?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ssh` from Python ([link](https://wiki.python.org/moin/SecureShell)).

Minimally, any `ssh` client will require the IP address of the remote machine (running `sshd`), the port on which `sshd` is listening and some credentials that authenticate the client to the remote machine (generally you'll want to use ssh-keys).

Google's SDKs (including the API Client Libraries for Python) help you interact with Google's services. You can use Google's Compute Engine API (and Python library) to provision (create) VMs including Linux VMs. You'll need to ensure the image you use runs `sshd` and the machine will need a (probably public) IP address. Once the command succeeds, you have a Linux VM mostly like any other (created on GCP, AWS, Azure etc.). You can query Compute Engine for the public IP address of an instance.

As long as you've ssh'd into a Google Compute Engine instance using `gcloud compute ssh ...` from your machine (any project), the command will have created a ssh key-pair for you that will be copied to your instances upon creation. You can then use the private key (`.ssh/google_compute_engine`) to authenticate your Python ssh client to the Compute Engine instance. You'll need to provide the IP address to the client too (it'll default to port `:22`).

**NB** `gcloud compute ssh ...` uses your machine's `ssh` client. It does not reimplement `ssh`. You can prove this to yourself by running `gcloud compute ssh --ssh-flag="-vvv"` or by temporarily making `which ssh` inaccessible to the gcloud command and trying `gcloud compute ssh ...` when `which ssh` is inaccessible to it; it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems though I cannot SSH into a remote VM instance with python but have to do this with command line. Is this right?

Yes, this is correct. You can automate to a point but not all the process as have you described.

One alternative way that I can think of is to use OS Login which manages the SSH access to your VM instances using IAM without having to create and manage individual SSH keys.

Comment: Can you go into a little more detail

Comment: I do not think you can automate everything with google-api-client, you can automate to some point like how you said with the yes/no questions but not all the steps necessary. You need to serve all the commands via CLI in most cases because you always will create a new instance of a CLI so you cannot really take beforehand the console since you do not know which one will you get.

That is why with OS Login you can simplify the process by linking to your account. More details in here about OS Login - https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/oslogin/

Answer (score 0):

You can run command on a remote instance directly from your app.

[Configure apps to use SSH](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/service-account-ssh) - there is a guide with code example for this use case in official documentation.